# A little confusion on P/Invoking C functions

Tags: c#, .net, c, interop, pinvoke

I am trying to create some bindings for some important functions in a library. Although I have a little confusion. Almost all of the main functions look like this(taken from a header):

```
     KBResult (*EnumScreens) (
          IKB              *thiz,
          IKCallback         callback,
          void                     *callbackdata
     );


     KBResult (*GetScreen) (
          IKB               *thiz,
          IKScreenID               screen_id,
          IKScreen         **ret_interface
     );

KBResult KBResult_API KBResultError(
                                          const char  *msg,    /* message */
                                          KBResultResult    result  /* result */
                                    );
```

My first confusion, is how how I write that when KBResult is in the front of each? Do I need to include that? The second questions is how do I pinvoke types that look like these:

```
 IKB              *thiz,
 IKCallback        callback,
 void             *callbackdata
```

Since it isn't something easy like int, I have no idea how to write that. Would this be what marshalling is for? Turning it into a similar type? I have had a heck of a time trying to figure these out. I have tried every tool out there besides swig(That is only because it literally wouldn't generate anything, might be my lack of experience), and every tool came up with massive amounts of errors. So I am deciding to do this by hand. Can anyone give me a hand in understanding this?

Comment: IKB, IKCallback, KBResult, etc. are specific to the library you use. You need to search what they mean, how are they defined in C so you can define equivalence in .NET. If you're not familiar with C, it may be an impossible task for you (no offense), maybe the library vendor could help.

Comment: The library's header file defines the types. You need to translate them.